# Invalid call at line 26: require('./pubimages/' + item.img)

Tags: reactjs, image, native

plz help this is my code
i can't read images
the erreur is Invalid call at line 26:

```
require('./pubimages/' + item.img)
item.image = nameimage.jpg

const renderItem = ({item}) => (
    <Card
                    featuredTitle={item.titre}
                    image={require('./pubimages/'+item.img)}>
                    <Text
                        style={{margin: 10}}>
                        {item.description}{console.log('./pubimages/'+item.img)}</Text>
                </Card>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In React you use `import` rather then `require`

Change `require('./pubimages/' + item.img)` to import `import imgaeName from './path/to/image'`